# Trigger WP_Query when its visible to the user (lazyload?)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I would like to trigger `WP_Query` if a particular `<div>` is visible to the users. In other words, I want to load the posts via `WP_Query` when a `<div>` is visible.

Here is a live example: http://androidpolice.com - click on the top menu (Apps/Games) then you can see their logo and after awhile the posts are loaded.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a method to execute the WP_Query somewhere in your functions.php. This method can be called with an ajax call from a js file. The js file contains a onclick or bind method to trigger the ajax call. The user clicks on the menu item and the onclick is fired.

Smashing magazine provides a fine tutorial http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to do it with WP_Query? Any idea on how to do it? Could you please send me the code for functions.php for the loop?